# Problema con Deno: Warning std versions prefixed with 'v' were deprecated recently

Tags: deno

Estoy tratando de ejecutar Deno cuando recibo el siguiente error:

Warning std versions prefixed with 'v' were deprecated recently. Please change your import to https://deno.land/std@0.51.0/io/util.ts (at https://deno.land/std@v0.51.0/io/util.ts)

error: Module not found "https://deno.land/std@v0.51.0/io/util.ts".
at https://deno.land/x/dejs@0.7.0/vendor/https/deno.land/std/io/util.ts:1:15

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a reinstalar, he estado buscando como solucionarlo pero nada me ha funcionado

Answer (score 0):

Dejs 0.7.0 desafortunadamente usa el prefijo std@vVERSION para importar la libreria std de Deno. Este prefijo fue removido en el ultimo año y reemplazado por std@VERSION.

Aunque hay varias maneras para solucionar este problema sin cambiar el codigo, la mas sencilla es cambiar la version de Dejs a 0.10.0

Actualiza el import de Dejs a algo similar a lo siguiente
`import * as dejs from "https://deno.land/x/dejs@0.10.2/mod.ts";`